# Shortcut/"Open with" Sublime Text, in a new Sublime window

Tags: sublimetext, windows-10

I am looking for a way to right click a file in Windows 10, select "Open with" -> "Sublime Text", and then have a *new* Sublime Text window appear.

The default action is to open the file in a new tab, if Sublime is already open. This is usually not what I want, especially since I usually have Sublime open on a different desktop.

I've tried making a shortcut with the `-n` flag added, which correctly gives me a new window when just using the shortcut. But when I "Open with" using that shortcut it opens the file in an existing window.

I also tried "Open with" a batch file containing `subl -n`, ``but alas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me (and is more comfortable for me than the Open with submenu):

1. Open `regedit.exe`
2. navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
   *To apply this only to certain file types replace the `*` with the appropiate extension*
3. Add key "Open With sublime in new window"
4. Inside this, add new key "command"
5. Inside "command" set the `(Default)` string to:
   `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe -n "%1"`

(basically copy the original keys, adding the `-n`)

6. Optional:
   Inside the key "Open With sublime in new window", add a string named `Icon`:
   `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe,0`
   This will add an the Sublime Text icon to the left of the command on the right-click menu.

---

To add the entries to the context menu for folders, add the same entries in:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
  *For the context menu when you click on a folder icon*
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
  *For the context menu when you click on the background of a folder*
  For this entry you must replace `"%1"` with `"%V"` (Thanks Filip)

Comment: This is pretty awesome, thanks! Not exactly what I asked, but a pretty good solution. Is it possible to make a similar registry key to create a "open Sublime here" appear when right clicking inside a folder, which would open the folder in Sublime (in a new instance/window)?

Comment: I discovered that it is possible to add the Sublime icon next to the command on the right-click menu. Inside the key "Open With sublime in new window", add a string named "Icon": `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe,0`

Comment: Yes, you can add this to a folder, just do the same addition to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell`. Note: It seems this only works when you click on the icon of a folder, not when you click on the background of a folder.

Comment: I added your suggested edit to the answer, I don't know why it was rejected. If I had seen it earlier I would have accepted the edit.

Comment: For folders I had to use the string `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe "%V"` instead of `"%1"`, and it doesn't look like the `-n` flag is needed for folders (you always get a new window).

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to use `%V` instead of `%1` for right clicking the background of folders (`%1` doesn't work for me), but the edit was rejected by 3 reviewers.

Comment: It seems `-n` is also not needed for opening files, either. I'm using Build 4107.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a script to do this, consider using the following in a batch script:

```
@echo off
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe

rem add it for folders
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f

rem add it for current folder
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%v\"" /f

pause
```

Put this in a .bat file (mine is called SetSublimeMenuShortcuts.bat) and then run in Powershell as an administrator user invoking it with .\SetSublimeMenuShortcuts.bat. If you see the following, it should be set properly:

```
The operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Open settings, then add the following line between { }:

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false
```

Comment: I am sure same option is available in Windows too

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the mac specific references, this way the answer is just as valid for windows.

Comment: It doesn't work for me though. Newly opened files open in new tabs, regardless if I set this setting to `true` or `false`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It worked for me. Refer the below link [https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6662]

Comment: Well, except it's exactly the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me (`true` and `false` behaves the same, opening files as a new tab, not a new window). In the docs it says "// OS X only:", so perhaps this setting doesn't affect anything on Windows?

Comment: Sorry it was wrong link. Please refer [https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3121]. When i remove it, then i am able to open always in new window.